# What is a good place to ask for bitcoin to fund a scientific project?

Tags: websites, donation, funds

I have a great idea for an invention, but I am currently limited to purchasing parts for building a prototype of it with bitcoins. Unfortunately, I do not have that many bitcoins and need a way to ask the bitcoin community for donations. Yes, I have an address, I am not a newbie to bitcoin. I would like to know where I can ask for bitcoin for a scientific project that could benefit the world. If anyone is interested I will disclose some information about my project.

Comment: bitcointalk.org might have a place for this.

Comment: if you have scientific project, most how about asking for a fund in university? Speak with different professors.

Answer (score 3):

You could look into posting about your project in the Einsteinium community. The coin is designed specifically to help fund science projects and research.

http://einsteinium.org/

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=494708.0